# Save-buttons in Joomla admin 3.6.5 stopped working

Tags: joomla, save

The buttons save and "save and close" have stoped working in Joomla admin-interface. It randomly saves every now and then... The problem occurs when saving the css-file too. I just upgraded to Joomla 3.6.5. Before it worked fine.

Comment: To rule out a cache problem, try installing the Web Developer Toolbar: http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/.  Once installed, click on it's Sprocket icon, then go to OPTIONS->RESET PAGE

Comment: I have installed the web developer plugin, but clicking on a sprocket does not give me any options like reseting the page... :(

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the Joomla cache and the web browser cache usually fixes this.